# SVG Render Issue - But only when external monitors connected (MacOS - chrome/firefox)

Tags: javascript, macos, svg, browser, rendering

I'm running into a very strange issue.

Somehow rendering an SVG via JS results in the it having weird offsets, but ONLY when my external monitors are connected.

I am on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2021. I can reproduce this issue on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Also, it doesn't matter on which monitor I am, it will happen on all screens, once I connect my two extra monitors (one 4k and one 1080p monitor)

[image]

You can see in the screenshot that there is a gap, even though the black area should fill the whole screen (which it does, if I disconnect the monitors).

I ran into this issue, when working on [a library](https://josias-r.github.io/boarding.js/).

In that library I highlight an element on the screen using an SVG, and because of these wierd offsets, the highlighting looks very odd:

[image]

It should be perfectly centered.

It is a really unfortunate issue, and I really have no clue where even to begin debugging it. Any help is appreciated!

```js
function createSVG() {
  console.log("render");

  const windowX = window.innerWidth;
  const windowY = window.innerHeight;

  const svgEl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  document.body.appendChild(svgEl);

  svgEl.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${windowX} ${windowY}`);
  // styles
  svgEl.style.position = "fixed";
  svgEl.style.top = "0";
  svgEl.style.left = "0";
  svgEl.style.right = "0";
  svgEl.style.bottom = "0";

  const pathEl = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "path"
  );
  pathEl.style.fill = "black";
  svgEl.appendChild(pathEl);

  pathEl.setAttribute(
    "d",
    `M${windowX},0L0,0L0,${windowY}L${windowX},${windowY}L${windowX},0Z`
  );

}
```

```html
<button onclick="createSVG()">render svg</button>
<div style="height: 150vh; position: relative;"></div>
```